# OpenVPN: не создаются ключи

Tags: linux, debian, vps, openvpn

Проблема на виртуальном сервере [Debian 7], с которого хочу раздавать интернет.

1. Установил **OpenVPN**.
2. Скопировал необходимые файлы в **/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/**.
3. Отредактировал **vars**.
4. При команде **source vars** - получаю вот такую вот фигу:

   bash: $'\r': command not found
    bash: $'\r': command not found
    bash: $'\r': command not found
    bash: $'\r': command not found
    bash: $'\r': command not found
    /whichopensslcnf: No such file or directory
    bash: $'\r': command not found
    bash: $'\r': command not found
    /keys If you run ./clean-all, I will be doing a rm -rf on /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
    bash: $'\r': command not found
    bash: $'\r': command not found
    bash: $'\r': command not found
    bash: $'\r': command not found
    bash: $'\r': command not found

Файл **openssl.cnf** и **whichopensslcnf** на месте.

Comment: @purplecoon, будьте добры, залейте файл vars куда-нибудь, похоже на то, что он почему-то пытается выполнить виндовые переводы строк, а часть пробелов исчезла. Если в файле vars какая-то секретная информация типа сидов генерации ключей (ей-богу ничего не знаю про openvpn) - никуда не заливайте, а повторите процедуру, лучше через nano прямо на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

Вот состояние файла с windows-переводом строки:

```
file vars
vars: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Вот нормальное состояние:

```
file vars
vars: ASCII English text
```

В обоих случаях он нормально исполняется и как ./vars и как source vars.

И проверьте, что у вас стоят все нужные пакеты:

```
ii  openvpn
ii  openvpn-blacklist
ii  libssl0.9.8
ii  openssl
ii  openssl-blacklist
ii  ssl-cert
```

И запуск вы производите в /etc/openvpn/2.0//

Желательно, конечно, на него глянуть.